# Even though I check there exsist a data, the error message shows "Cannot read properties of undefined" in React

Tags: reactjs

I am just getting started learning `React` one month ago. I am sorry if I asked a pretty easy question in advance.

Here is an issue,

- what's the problem?
  : I got data from back-end that is called "setWeekendEventData". When I console WeekendEventData, I can check I received the data that I want.
  [image: WeekendEventData]

Here, I only want DayName. In this case, there are two `DayName`s. So, I tried to use the 'map' method because sometimes the `DayName` could be one or two or more than three.
First, I tried to like this

```
{weekendEventData.map((obj, index) => {
                return <RedText>{obj[index].DayName}</RedText>;
              })}
```

However, I got this error message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DayName')"

- What I tried to do

1. 

```
{weekendEventData && weekendEventData.map((obj, index) => {
                return <RedText>{obj[index].DayName}</RedText>;
              })}
```

and

```
{[] && weekendEventData.map((obj, index) => {
                return <RedText>{obj[index].DayName}</RedText>;
              })}
```

I add the `&&` condition to make it always true but there is the same error message. Usually, I solved this kind of error message by using && condition but it didn't work this time.

2. Using "Condition ? : " but it also didn't work

- What I expected: It should be return DayName which is '개천절' and '한글날'

I would really appreciate your comments or solution!

edit 1:

```
const holiday = data => {
    let array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
      if (data) {
        if (array.includes(data[i])) i++;
        else array.push(data[i]);
      }
      console.log("데이터 값", data[i]);
      console.log("휴무일 배열", array);
    }
```

and in the functional component

```
<RedText>{holiday(weekendData)}</RedText>
```

Comment: You can directly access dayName in the map function no need to do using index-like.
You can directly access DayName in the map function. {obj.DayName}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `index` wrongly here

```
obj[index].DayName
```

It should be corrected safely as below

```
obj.DayName || ""
```

Following will work with duplicates removed

```
<RedText>
    {weekendEventData &&
        weekendEventData
            .reduce((prevValue, currValue) => {
                prevValue.indexOf(currValue.DayName) < 0 &&
                    prevValue.push(currValue.DayName);
                return prevValue;
            }, [])
            .join(", ")}
</RedText>
```

Comment: @JiwanJeon94, check this out !!

Comment: First of all, thank you for trying to help me out! I tried to follow up your solution but I got this error message " Unexpected token (643:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type." Could you check What should I do?

Comment: @JiwanJeon94, seems optional chaining (comes from ES2020 version) is not supported in your project setup. I have updated the answer now

Comment: Oh I got your point! It works as well! If you don't mind, can I ask one more question?

Comment: yes sure, can you please mark this as the answer if it helped to solve your issue?

Comment: My mistake sorry. I miss one thing that if the obj.DayName same as the previous one. It should be show only one time. For example, if first and second and third one have same name as "test", it only show only one test not a test test test.

Comment: I am currently using styled-component but I have no idea what should I do..

Comment: I am trying to use make a function and call it but it didn't work...

Comment: I add the code that I said above! Please check the Edit 1 part :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand how to code it! If I want to add ',' comma between the item, what should I do? I did {item + ","} but you know I don't need the last ',' Like, list1,list2 not a list1,list2,

Comment: I really appreciate your help! :) Have a good one!